# How declaration of nested arrays interpreted in Ruby?

Tags: ruby

While i was working on arrays, I missed a comma in declaration of the nested array in Ruby but language interpreting this in other way. If anyone familiar about this behaviour please give a thought.

```
arr = [1,2[1,8]]
[1, 1] 
arr = [1,5[6,4]]
[1, 0] 
arr = [1,3[1,6]]
[1, 1] 
arr = [1,6[1,6]]
[1, 3] 
arr = [1,7[1,6]]
[1, 3] 
arr = [1,0[1,6]]
[1, 0] 
arr = [1,8[1,6]]
[1, 4]
```

An exception should be raised based on False Declaration

Comment: What you accidentally ended up using is https://docs.ruby-lang.org/en/3.0/Integer.html#method-i-5B-5D.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> An exception should be raised [...]

`[1,8[1,6]]` might look like a syntax error in the context of an array literal but it's actually a perfectly valid Ruby expression. It creates an array with two elements: `1` and the result from `8[1,6]` which is `4`.

`8[1,6]` extracts a part of the integer `8`. It does this by treating `8` as a sequence of bits (the binary number 00001000₂). From these bits, 6 bits are extracted, starting at bit 1: (with bit 0 being the *right*-most bit)

```
0b00001000[1,6]  #=> 8
   ↓↓↓↓↓↓
 0b000100        #=> 4
```

See the docs for [`Integer#[]`](https://docs.ruby-lang.org/en/3.3/Integer.html#method-i-5B-5D) for details.

This is very similar to `"hello ruby"[1,6]` which extracts a part of the string by treating it as a sequence of characters: (with character 0 being the *left*-most character)

```
"hello ruby"[1,6]
  ↓↓↓↓↓↓
 "ello r"
```